# What if we can't find the difference in AB test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test

What if we do tests, try reduce variance, but still can't get low p-value to reject the hypothesis. How to find out that there's no difference, and if so we can choose variant B just because we like it more?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Might you mean [equivalence testing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have done an appropriately powered test that would have very likely found meaningful effect sizes if they were really there, then a lack of significance suggest that there truly is no meaningful difference. You can choose as you like between A and B - your analysis has told you that your choice *does not matter*. Now, if you haven't collected enough data and are attempting an underpowered analysis, then a lack of significance doesn't really tell you anything at all - it's possible to find an insignificant p-value either by looking very hard and finding no evidence, or just by not collecting any evidence in the first place.

Comment: +1 “Well how hard did ya look?” is my first thought when research claims no difference. The answer could be that the researcher looked really hard, but it also could be that the researcher did not look hard.

Comment: +1. @Dave, I don't know about that.. Sometimes I have the feeling there is so much slicing and dicing that winner's curse in A/B (or general hypothesis) testing can be a big factor (see Lee & Shen 2018 in KDD '18). In some cases I am almost like: "What's the SNR here? If this treatment is so darn good why do we have to use all these corrections to actually see it?"

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Nuclear Hoagie's nice answer (+1).

Finding out that there is no difference between the arms of A and B is *fine*. Detecting positive differences can actually be quite hard when working in an already optimized environment or setting. To quote Kohavi et al. (2009) [Online Experimentation at Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/online-experimentation-at-microsoft/): "*Evaluating well-designed and executed experiments that were designed to improve a key metric, only about one-third were successful at improving the key metric!*" That said, do note that we often have heterogeneous treatment effects, especially within the context of A/B tests where the concept of an Average Treatment Effect might be ill-defined (for example, if we have mobile & desktop users from different demographics put together). In such cases, looking at a CATE (Conditional Average Treatment Effect) might be more enlightening, Imai & Ratkovic (2013) [Estimating treatment effect heterogeneity in randomized program evaluation](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-statistics/volume-7/issue-1/Estimating-treatment-effect-heterogeneity-in-randomized-program-evaluation/10.1214/12-AOAS593.full) is considered pretty much a classic if one wants to start on the subject.